# JavaFX or Swing and XInput2

Tags: java, linux, swing, javafx, x11

It is possible to make Swing or `JavaFX` support `XInput2`? Maybe it is possible to use XInput2 class from LWJGL3?

I need multi-touch support on `Linux`, but `JavaFX` nor `Swing` register any touch events. In the same time `xinput test-ix2` displays touch events correctly. On Windows `JavaFX` displays touch events. 
Under Linux I use JRE 7, but under Windows I am using JRE 8.

Comment: It's unlikely, as all three have different rendering pipelines

Comment: Related: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3541495 (The [JavaFX JIRA link](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-25079) requires a login which I don't currently have;  perhaps someone who has one can describe the current state of that entry.)

Comment: So it seems that `multi-touch` will work in JavaFX if I rebuild it with specific options: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2014-April/013286.html
However, it is not an easy solution.